# publish application in release mode and automatically set debug to false

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Before I publish my project I need to set it to release mode and also set the debug flag to false in the web.config file. Is there a way to use preprocessor directives to set the debug flag to false if the release symbol is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create web.config file transformations that are dependent on current build configuration. Take a look at: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-web-config-file-transformations-3-of-12

Comment: Adding `<system.web><compilation targetFramework="4.5" xdt:Transform="Replace" /></system.web>` to the Web.Release.Config works.

Comment: `<compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />` also works.